# Is there a way to install Google Cloud Shell Theia extensions?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I want to edit some programing languages files with help of Theia, but default extension list doesn't contain their language-server extension.

It looks impossible for me, but I'm not certain.
Official documentation about Google Cloud Shell doesn't explain about how their Theia-based editor service is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to install new extensions into the Cloud Shell's Theia editor as the configuration of the Cloud Shell VM is curated by Google. However, Cloud Shell VMs are [updated weekly](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#image_rollout), so please submit in-product feedback for any specific requests for the team to consider.